# How do i take ABCD out of a mySQL database and make it into a pie chart?

Tags: php, mysql, pie-chart

I have a MySQL database that responses can be answered into as A, B, C, or D. I want to now take these answers out of the MySQL database and put them into an pie chart. How is this possible, easily?

Can I some how get it as an array and parse the array? but how to access this array?

Thanks

Comment: Look into SQL's `GROUP BY` and aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

```
SELECT A, COUNT(A), B, COUNT(B) FROM answer GROUP BY answ;
```